# How to fill the blank space at the bottom of grid view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-relativelayout

My project had fragment which has Main Relative Layout. Relative Layout had layout width and height match_parent. It contains Grid Layout at the top. After grid layout linear layout is added to separate the remaining portion of screen.
Below of the linear layout grid view is added. Here is the  problem arrived.
My grid view contains nine element. On small device it fill entire screen, but when device screen is large enough the the blank space is getting added at the end. I want to fill the entire screen with 9 element on every device, may be device size is small or large.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="yieldcurve.jamakharch.SavingsFragment">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gl_savings_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:rowCount="2">

    <yieldcurve.jamakharch.util.JTextViewRegular
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="9"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/total_savings"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="0.1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:background="@color/colorLine" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_savings_refresh"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="22"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_reset" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="200"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_savings_minus"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_minus" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorLine" />

        <yieldcurve.jamakharch.util.JCustomBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_total_savings_value"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="200."
            android:textColor="@color/colorTracklabels"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <yieldcurve.jamakharch.util.JCustomBoldTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_saving_unit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="L"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTracklabels"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorLine" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_savings_plus"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_show_saving_chart"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_show_map" />
</GridLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/savings_seperator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gl_savings_header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@color/colorLine"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/savings_seperator">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_track_savings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"></GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` of `GridLayout`

Answer (score 0):

change android:layout_height="wrap_content" to android:layout_height="match_parent" and your parent viewgroup is Relative layout so android:layout_weight="1" not work.

android:layout_weight is used for only Linear layout.